# I don't want to write 60 'IF' commands

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

- 60 questions answered in google-forms
- every question has 2 answer options, for example

  ```
          Q1.Select your Gender 
           A.Male
           B.Female
  ```
- google-sheet gives me 60 cells in one row with chosen answer for example `Male` or `Female`
- ans are then supposed to be categorised in 4 category with 2 sub category `[E`,`I]` `[S`, `N]` `[T`, `F]` `[J`, `P]`
- I do not want to code like this `IF(B21="Male", "E", "I")` 60 times
- each category is added for example `[E=10, I=5], [S=9, N=6], [T=7, F=8], [J=4, P=11]`
- then four highest category chosen as the result for that individual in this case it would be **`E S F P`**
  Just FYI, doing all the calculation on a different sheet, populating the sheet with a Query function `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("form_id","Form Responses 1!A:df"),"",1)`.
- Mockup form https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/163UHYGKqzABTq3ccnGzndYZvL-okuMiAKFNAwEIvUOI/edit?usp=sharing
- **Thanx for your time**
- **Please Refer to the Sheet** I have added the actual paper questionniere

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209998/discussion-on-question-by-joy4u2-i-dont-want-to-write-60-if-commands).

Answer (score 0):

use arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B21:B81="Male", "E", "I"))
```

Comment: thank you for your time, in actual case there will be 120 different answers in google form and it will give 60 answers which the subject selects, please refer to the sheet